# LoadLibrary failed - The specified module could not be found

Tags: c++, dll, regsvr32

First off, I found and read this:

[LoadLibrary project.dll failed. The specified module could not be found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11717312/loadlibrary-project-dll-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found)

I'm running:

```
    Windows 10 Enterprise
    Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-4300U CPU @ 1.90GHz 2.49 GHz
    8.00 GB (7.69 GB usable)
    64-bit Operating System, x64-based processor
```

According to "ver":

```
    Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.17134.167]
```

Unfortunately I couldn't get the "Dependency Walker" application to open the DLL, when I selected the problem file it just went into a "Not responding" state and doesn't recover.

I'm registering a bunch of DLL's and all ok with the exception of one, it builds without errors but I get this when I attempt to register:

[image]

Edit:  "Dependency Walker" does run, just goes into a Not Responding state for a long time, but eventually it comes back.

How do interpret the results to resolve the issues?

```
    API_MS-WIN-CORE-APIQUERY-L1-1-0.DLL
    Error opening file. The system cannot find the file specified(2).
```

Same error reported for:

```
    API_MS-WIN-CORE_APPCOMPAT-L1-1-0.DLL
    API_MS-WIN-CORE_APPCOMPAT-L1-1-1.DLL
    API_MS-WIN-CORE_APPINIT-L1-1-0.DLL
    API_MS-WIN-CORE_ATOMS-L1-1-0.DLL
    API_MS-WIN-CORE_COM-L1-1-0.DLL
    API_MS-WIN-CORE_COM-L1-1-2.DLL
```

And many more DLL's

Comment: The dependency walker website is out of date, if you use the new one it wont crash: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8832936/profiling-x86-executable-with-dependency-walker-hangs-on-windows-7-x64

Comment: @AlanBirtles, I just downloaded both the 32 bit and 64 bit versions from the web-site and neither work, where can I get one that works?

Comment: I have now run "Dependency Walker" on the DLL and have a file with the results, but I see no way of uploading this and I'm not sure what it means or how to interpret it, there are a lot of issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After waiting for "Dependency Walker" to finally come back, I could see that a referenced DLL was missing from the system.

I've now resolved this issue by installing the missing DLL.

Answer (score 0):

Be aware of is that the program loading a DLL may have different loading paths compared to those shown in DependencyWalker, for instance if the program calls [SetDllDirectoryA](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setdlldirectorya). A useful debugging tool is the [Show Loader Snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps) flag (image-file, not global, otherwise it only affects the kernel). The easiest way to set it is likely with gflags.exe.

This will give very specific debug information, including the paths searched and the specific dll that was not found.

```
46a0:24bc @ -748636031 - LdrpProcessWork - ERROR: Unable to load DLL: "dependency.dll", Parent Module: "C:\fullpath\to\parent.dll", Status: 0xc0000135
```